# Walking an LDAP tree and creating nodes from top to bottom - right approach?

Tags: ldap

I have an LDAP subtree, whose entries correspond to a tree-like structure of Java Objects. Using this subtree, I need to build the tree top-down, because each node of the tree knows its parent node but not it's child (I am not able to change the implementation).

So, I first thought to grab the entries in one search but I've read somewhere that the entries could be returned in any order (probably implementation-specific I guess).

So, am I right in my assumption, that I need to recursivly traverse the LDAP tree, one level at a time, building my tree top-down? Or are there better approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. Not only are attributes, attribute values, and entries [not ordered](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/a-common-mistake-made-by-programmers-is-to-expect-ldap-attributes-and-attribute-values-to-be-ordered/), the ordering is not repeatable. Also, the server administrators may configure the server to only allow non-root DN authentication states to retrieve a few entries at a time, or limit searches in the time the server will use processing the search, therefore, retrieving all entries may not work at all. For more general information on programming with LDAP, see "[LDAP: Programming Practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)".

Comment: Hey Terry, I noticed you've been using some URL shorteners fairly often recently - on StackOverflow, [we much prefer it if you'd use the full, non-shortened link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup). Just letting you know!